# Javascript add multiple if - window.location.hostname

Tags: javascript

I have 5 websites using the same DB, and I need to add an global .js to check window.location.hostname and redirect if dont match one of my domains:

```
if (window.location.hostname != 'mysite1.com') 
if (window.location.hostname != 'mysite2.com') 
if (window.location.hostname != 'mysite3.com') 
if (window.location.hostname != 'mysite4.com') 
if (window.location.hostname != 'mysite5.com') 
{
   window.location.href = 'https://google.com'; 
}
```

The js will be inserted in the DB, and will display in all my sites.

**HOW to add multiple instances of IF...window.location.hostname ... in the RIGHT WAY**

Comment: And the question is?...

Comment: Why would this code stop the clones of your site?

Comment: HOW to add multiple instances of IF... in the RIGHT WAY

Comment: This will do nothing to stop clones of your site.

Comment: Will not stop the clone, but will redirect from clone to other site

Comment: This is an example - http://filme5.com will redirect to an cam-chat

Comment: If I were to disable JavaScript, your website wouldn't redirect me anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if I understood your question. If you want to merge those 'if' conditions you can do like this:

```
if(!['mysite1.com','mysite2.com','mysite3.com','mysite4.com','mysite5.com'].includes(window.location.hostname)){
            window.location.href = 'https://google.com'; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's perfect

Answer (score 1):

Change your code and add AND as follows:

```
if (window.location.hostname != 'mysite1.com'
&& window.location.hostname != 'mysite2.com' 
&& window.location.hostname != 'mysite3.com' 
&& window.location.hostname != 'mysite4.com' 
&& window.location.hostname != 'mysite5.com') 
{
   window.location.href = 'https://google.com'; 
}
```

Comment: This condition will always be true.  If the hostname is `mysite1.com`, it cannot also be `mysite2.com`.

Comment: I changed the ORs to ANDs. That should fix it.

Comment: Thanks! I've made a typo.

Answer (score 0):

I would define a list (array) of all domains first and then check if the current domain is on the list

```
listOfHostnames = ['mysite1.com', 'mysite2.com', 'mysite3.com'];

if (!~window.location.hostname.indexOf(listOfHostnames)) {
    window.location.href = 'https://google.com';
}
```